# How does this comparator class work?

Tags: java, hibernate, comparator, sortedset

I found this comparator class in this site.

[Hibernate - SortedSet Mappings](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_sortedset_mapping.htm)

But I can't understand how it works..
Any ideas??

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyClass implements Comparator<Certificate>{
   public int compare(Certificate o1, Certificate o2) {
      final int BEFORE = -1;
      final int AFTER = 1;

      /* To reverse the sorting order, multiple by -1 */
      if (o2 == null) {
         return BEFORE * -1;
      }

      Comparable thisCertificate = o1.getName();
      Comparable thatCertificate = o2.getName();

      if(thisCertificate == null) {
         return AFTER * 1;
      } else if(thatCertificate == null) {
         return BEFORE * -1;
      } else {
         return thisCertificate.compareTo(thatCertificate) * -1;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you check **that** it really works? Because that doesn't look like it. Especially the `null` handling is very strange and if I am not wrong will result in a unstable search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works? In documentation says it is doing reverse sorting,

> If we use sort="natural" setting then we do not need to create a separate class because Certificate class already has implemented Comparable interface and hibernate will use compareTo() method defined in Certificate class to compare certificate names. But we are using a custom comparator class MyClass in our mapping file so we would have to create this class based on our sorting algorithm. **Let us do descending sorting in this class using this class.**

In my understand seems to not be really correct... Except when both certificate names are correct.

```
public int compare(Certificate o1, Certificate o2) {
  final int BEFORE = -1;
  final int AFTER = 1;

  /* To reverse the sorting order, multiple by -1 */
  if (o2 == null) {       // if o2 = null > o1 goes first
     return BEFORE * -1;  // -1 * -1 = 1 so o1 goes first
  }

  Comparable thisCertificate = o1.getName();  // get o1 name to compare
  Comparable thatCertificate = o2.getName();  // get o2 name to compare

  if(thisCertificate == null) {         // if o1 name is null, o2 goes first
     return AFTER * 1;                  // 1 * 1 = 1 > o1 goes first
  } else if(thatCertificate == null) {  // if o2 name is null, o1 goes first
     return BEFORE * -1;                // -1 * -1 = 1 > o1 goes first
  } else {                              
     // if both certs names are valid compare them in the usual way 
     //  sorting inversed because of the -1.
     return thisCertificate.compareTo(thatCertificate) * -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This comparator doesn't work at all, since it violates the most basic [rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) of how a `Comparator` works.

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y

`Comparator.compare(x , y) == -Comparator.compare(y,x)` isn't valid if `x` or `y` is `null` when using `MyClass`.

> (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception.)

the case `o1 == null` isn't handled at all and thus will throw an exception, while the case `o2 == null` doesn't.

This is far from what a working comparator looks like and can atmost be looked on as a **really ugly hack**.
This `Comparator` only works for values that aren't `null`. In that case it is simply the reverse of the natural order.